# Pound Sign (#) As Comment Start In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comments, npm, jshint, uglifyjs2

Does the pound sign (#) start a comment in JavaScript? I have a website I am using with NPM and when I tried to minify the JavaScript with Grunt, Uglify threw the error:

```
Warning: Uglification failed.
Unexpected character '#'.
Line 1 in app/min-libs/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/node_modules/jshint/nod
e_modules/cli/examples/cat.js
 Use --force to continue.
```

The file name being referred to seems to be from another NPM module, meaning they know what they are doing. So when I went to app/min-libs/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/node_modules/jshint/node_modules/cli/examples/cat.js, the offending line says:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Is this a comment or do the owners of this NPM module know some super-secret forbidden JavaScript technique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a JavaScript technique, but a *nix OS one. It is called [`shebang`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). Quoting from Wiki

> Under Unix-like operating systems, when a script with a shebang is run
>   as a program, the program loader parses the rest of the script's
>   initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter
>   program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was
>   initially used when attempting to run the scrip

So, the `cat.js` file can be executed in the shell, like an executable (if it has executable permission).

```
cat.js
```

instead of

```
node cat.js
```

Comment: Wow, you learn something new every day. I guess I'll have to find a way to get Uglify to ignore files that have this shebang thing. Thanks.

Comment: If I may ask, @thefourtheye, where did your profile name come from? I know the 3rd eye is the eye that can see the imagination or something, so what is the 4th eye?

Comment: @trysis You are welcome :) As per hindu mythology [lord Shiva has three eyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiva#Attributes). Since he has the name the third eye, I took the fourth eye :P