# What exactly does "/usr/bin/env node" do at the beginning of node files?

Tags: node.js, shebang

I had seen this line `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the beginning of some examples in `nodejs` and I had googled without finding any topic that could answer the reason for that line.

The nature of the words makes search it not that easy.

I'd read some `javascript` and `nodejs` books recently and I didn't remember seeing it in any of them.

If you want an example, you could see the `RabbitMQ` official [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-javascript.html), they have it in almost all of their examples, here is one of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var ex = 'logs';
    var msg = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ') || 'Hello World!';

    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', {durable: false});
    ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(msg));
    console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
  });

  setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);
});
```

Could someone explain me what is the meaning of this line?

What is the difference if I put or remove this line? In what cases do I need it?

Comment: it basically takes the environment of the calling shell and stuffs that environment into whatever app is specified. in this case, `node`

Comment: Actually no, I am not comming from Windows, but thank you for updating your answer. I am just waiting to see if anyone else cames with a diferent opinion. There is just one thing that I think you didn't mention in your answer, I just find it a couple of hours ago. The things that they mention here seems kind of important but it is not clear enough yet for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517535/directly-call-globally-installed-node-js-modules (you can update if you want, I will really apreciate that,  but don't feel it like an obligation, your answer is good enough right now).

Comment: @Gepser: Got it. The short of it is: if you want `npm` to install a Node.js source script as a (potentially globally available) _CLI_, you _must_ use a shebang line - and `npm` will even make that work on Windows; see my once-again updated answer.

Comment: _"The nature of the words makes search it not that easy"_ –  you may want to try https://duckduckgo.com for this specific search use case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do people write the #!/usr/bin/env python shebang on the first line of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2429511/608639). Same question, different interpreter.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env node` is **an instance of a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))**: the *very first line in an executable plain-text file on **Unix-like platforms** that tells the system what interpreter to pass that file to for execution*, via the command line following the magic `#!` prefix (called *shebang*).

Note: ***Windows* does *not* support shebang lines**, so they're effectively *ignored* there; on Windows it is solely a given file's *filename extension* that determines what executable will interpret it. **However, you still need them in the context of `npm`**.<sup>[1]</sup>

The following, **general discussion of shebang lines** is limited to Unix-like platforms:

<sup>In the following discussion I'll assume that the file containing source code for execution by Node.js is simply named `file`.</sup>

- You **NEED this line**, if you want to invoke a Node.js source file *directly*, as an executable in its own right - this assumes that the file has been marked as executable with a command such as `chmod +x ./file`, which then allows you to invoke the file with, for instance, `./file`, or, if it's located in one of the directories listed in the `$PATH` variable, simply as `file`.

  - Specifically, you need a shebang line to create *CLIs* based on Node.js source files as part of an npm *package*, with the CLI(s) to be installed by `npm` based on the value of the [`"bin"` key in a package's `package.json` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin); also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22767508/45375) for how that works with *globally* installed packages. Footnote [1] shows how this is handled on Windows.
- You **do NOT need** this line to invoke a file explicitly via the `node` interpreter, e.g., `node ./file`

---

**Optional background information**:

`#!/usr/bin/env <executableName>` is a way of *portably* specifying an interpreter: in a nutshell, it says: execute `<executableName>` wherever you (first) find it among the directories listed in the `$PATH` variable (and implicitly pass it the path to the file at hand).

This accounts for the fact that a given interpreter may be installed in different locations across platforms, which is definitely the case with `node`, the Node.js binary.

By contrast, the location of the `env` utility itself can be relied upon to be in the *same* location across platforms, namely `/usr/bin/env` - and specifying the *full* path to an executable is *required* in a shebang line.

Note that POSIX utility `env` is being *repurposed* here to locate by filename and execute an executable in the `$PATH`.
The true purpose of `env` is to manage the environment for a command - see [`env`'s POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) and [Keith Thompson's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33513915/45375).

---

It's also worth noting that Node.js is making a syntax *exception* for shebang lines, given that they're not valid JavaScript code (`#` is not a comment character in JavaScript, unlike in POSIX-like shells and other interpreters).

---

<sup>[1] In the interest of cross-platform consistency, **`npm` creates *wrapper* `*.cmd` files (batch files) on Windows** when installing executables specified in a package's `package.json` file (via the `"bin"` property). Essentially, these wrapper batch files *mimic* Unix shebang functionality: they **invoke the target file explicitly with the executable specified in the shebang line** - thus, **your scripts must include a shebang line even if you only ever intend to run them on Windows** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44468968/45375) of mine for details.

Since `*.cmd` files can be invoked without the `.cmd` extension, this makes for a seamless cross-platform experience: on both Windows and Unix you can effectively invoke an `npm`-installed CLI by its original, extension-less name.</sup>

Comment: Can you provide an explanation or summary for dummies like me?

Comment: @AndrewLam: On Windows, filename extensions such as `.cmd` and `.py` determine what program will be used to execute such files. On Unix, the shebang line performs that function.  To make `npm` work on all supported platforms, you need the shebang line even on Windows.

Answer (score 40):

Scripts that are to be executed by an interpreter normally have a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top to tell the OS how to execute them.

If you have a script named `foo` whose first line is `#!/bin/sh`, the system will read that first line and execute the equivalent of `/bin/sh foo`. Because of this, most interpreters are set up to accept the name of a script file as a command-line argument.

The interpreter name following the `#!` has to be a full path; the OS won't search your `$PATH` to find the interpreter.

If you have a script to be executed by `node`, the obvious way to write the first line is:

```
#!/usr/bin/node
```

but that doesn't work if the `node` command isn't installed in `/usr/bin`.

A common workaround is to use the `env` command (which wasn't *really* intended for this purpose):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

If your script is called `foo`, the OS will do the equivalent of

```
/usr/bin/env node foo
```

The `env` command executes another command whose name is given on its command line, passing any following arguments to that command.  The reason it's used here is that `env` will search `$PATH` for the command.  So if `node` is installed in `/usr/local/bin/node`, and you have `/usr/local/bin` in your `$PATH`, the `env` command will invoke `/usr/local/bin/node foo`.

The main purpose of the `env` command is to execute another command with a modified environment, adding or removing specified environment variables before running the command.  But with no additional arguments, it just executes the command with an unchanged environment, which is all you need in this case.

There are some drawbacks to this approach. Most modern Unix-like systems have `/usr/bin/env`, but I worked on older systems where the `env` command was installed in a different directory. There might be limitations on additional arguments you can pass using this mechanism. If the user *doesn't* have the directory containing the `node` command in `$PATH`, or has some different command called `node`, then it could invoke the wrong command or not work at all.

Other approaches are:

- Use a `#!` line that specifies the full path to the `node` command itself, updating the script as needed for different systems; or
- Invoke the `node` command with your script as an argument.

See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) (and [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454)) for more discussion of the `#!/usr/bin/env` trick.

Incidentally, on my system (Linux Mint 17.2), it's installed as `/usr/bin/nodejs`.  According to my notes, it changed from `/usr/bin/node` to `/usr/bin/nodejs` between Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10. The `#!/usr/bin/env` trick won't help with that (unless you set up a symlink or something similar).

UPDATE: A comment by mtraceur says (reformatted):

> A workaround for the nodejs vs node problem is to start the file with
>   the following six lines:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh -
> ':' /*-
> test1=$(nodejs --version 2>&1) && exec nodejs "$0" "$@"
> test2=$(node --version 2>&1) && exec node "$0" "$@"
> exec printf '%s\n' "$test1" "$test2" 1>&2
> */
> ```
>
> This will first try `nodejs` and then try `node`, and only
>   print the error messages if both of them are not found. An explanation
>   is out of scope of these comments, I'm just leaving it here in case it
>   helps anyone deal with the problem since this answer brought the
>   problem up.

I haven't used NodeJS lately.  My hope is that the `nodejs` vs. `node` issue has been resolved in the years since I first posted this answer. On Ubuntu 18.04, the `nodejs` package installs `/usr/bin/nodejs` as a symlink to `/usr/bin/node`. On some earlier OS (Ubuntu or Linux Mint, I'm not sure which), there was a `nodejs-legacy` package that provided `node` as a symlink to `nodejs`. No guarantee that I have all the details right.

Comment: A very thorough answer providing why of things.

Comment: A workaround for the `nodejs` vs `node` problem is to start the file with the following six lines: 1) `#!/bin/sh -`, 2) `':' /*-` 3) `test1=$(nodejs --version 2>&1) && exec nodejs "$0" "$@"` 4) `test2=$(node --version 2>&1) && exec node "$0" "$@"`, 5) `exec printf '%s\n' "$test1" "$test2" 1>&2` 6) `*/`. This will first try `nodejs` and then try `node`, and only print the error messages if both of them are not found. An explanation is out of scope of these comments, I'm just leaving it here in case it helps anyone deal with the problem since this answer brought the problem up.

Comment: @mtraceur: I've incorporated your comment into my answer. Why the `-` on the `#!` line?

Comment: The `-` in `#!/bin/sh -` is just a habit that makes sure the shell behaves right in the extremely narrow and unlikely set of circumstances that the script name or relative path that the shell sees starts with a `-`. (Also, yes, it looks like every mainstream distro had converged back to `node` as the primary name. I didn't go digging to check when making my comment, but as far as I know only the Debian distro family tree used `nodejs`, and it looks like they all reverted back to also supporting `node` once Debian did.)

Comment: Technically the single dash as first argument did not mean "end of options" - it originally meant "turn off `-x` and `-v`", but since the early Bourne-likes only parsed the first argument as possible options, and since the shell starts with those options off, it was abusable to cause the shell to not try to parse the script name since the original, and remains thusly abusable because the behavior is maintained in modern Bourne-likes for compatibility reasons. If I remember all my Bourne history and portability trivia right.

Comment: I think every modern Bourne-like shell supports the more recognizable convention of `--` being used to signal the end of options, but I am afflicted with a rare brain disease that forces me to prefer shell scripting habits that will work on the widest range of Bourne-like shells unless there is a compelling reason otherwise. I tend to not remember or think about the interdependencies between those habits, which is why I stuck with `-` instead of `--` even though I used the `$(` substitution instead of backticks and did `"$@"` without handling the ancient bug in the case of no arguments.

Answer (score 6):

**The `exec` system call of the Linux kernel understands shebangs (`#!`) natively**

When you do on bash:

```
./something
```

on Linux, this calls the `exec` system call with the path `./something`.

This line of the kernel gets called on the file passed to `exec`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_script.c#L25

```
if ((bprm->buf[0] != '#') || (bprm->buf[1] != '!'))
```

It reads the very first bytes of the file, and compares them to `#!`.

If the comparison is true, then the rest of the line is parsed by the Linux kernel, which makes another `exec` call with:

- executable: `/usr/bin/env`
- first argument: `node`
- second argument: script path

therefore equivalent to:

```
/usr/bin/env node /path/to/script.js
```

`env` is an executable that searches `PATH` to e.g. find `/usr/bin/node`, and then finally calls:

```
/usr/bin/node /path/to/script.js
```

The Node.js interpreter does see the `#!` line in the file, but it must be programmed to ignore that line even though `#` is not in general a valid comment character in Node (unlike many other languages such as Python where it is), see also: [Pound Sign (#) As Comment Start In JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036928/pound-sign-as-comment-start-in-javascript)

And yes, you can make an infinite loop with:

```
printf '#!/a\n' | sudo tee /a
sudo chmod +x /a
/a
```

Bash recognizes the error:

```
-bash: /a: /a: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

`#!` just happens to be human readable, but that is not required.

If the file started with different bytes, then the `exec` system call would use a different handler. The other most important built-in handler is for ELF executable files: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1305 which checks for bytes `7f 45 4c 46` (which also happens to be human readable for `.ELF`). Let's confirm that by reading the 4 first bytes of `/bin/ls`, which is an ELF executable:

```
head -c 4 "$(which ls)" | hd
```

output:

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46                                       |.ELF|
00000004
```

So when the kernel sees those bytes, it takes the ELF file, puts it into memory correctly, and starts a new process with it. See also: [How does kernel get an executable binary file running under linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861)

Finally, you can add your own shebang handlers with the `binfmt_misc` mechanism. For example, you can add a [custom handler for `.jar` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667830/running-a-jar-file-without-directly-calling-java). This mechanism even supports handlers by file extension. Another application is to [transparently run executables of a different architecture with QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-filesystem-with-a-different-architechture).

I don't think [POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755) specifies shebangs however: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346214/32558 , although it does mention in on rationale sections, and in the form "if executable scripts are supported by the system something may happen". macOS and FreeBSD also seem to implement it however.

**`PATH` search motivation**

Likely, one big motivation for the existence of shebangs is the fact that in Linux, we often want to run commands from `PATH` just as:

```
basename-of-command
```

instead of:

```
/full/path/to/basename-of-command
```

But then, without the shebang mechanism, how would Linux know how to launch each type of file?

Hardcoding the extension in commands:

```
 basename-of-command.js
```

or implementing PATH search on every interpreter:

```
node basename-of-command
```

would be a possibility, but this has the major problem that everything breaks if we ever decide to refactor the command into another language.

Shebangs solve this problem beautifully.

Comment: You have mentioned /usr/bin/node /path/to/script.py , but i think you actually meant /usr/bin/node /path/to/script.js. Please correct the snippet. Currently edit queue is full. Or I could have edited.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
It is the path to the interpreter.

EDIT (Long Answer):
The reason there is no slash before "node" is because you can not always guarantee the reliability of #!/bin/ . The "/env" bit makes the program more cross-platform by running the script in a modified environment and more reliably being able to find the interpreter program.

You do not necessarily need it, but it is good to use to ensure portability (and professionalism)

Comment: The `/usr/bin/env` bit doesn't modify the environment. It's just a command at a (mostly) known location that invokes another command given as an argument, and searches `$PATH` to find it. The point is that the `#!` line requires the full path to the command being invoked, and you don't necessarily know where `node` is installed.

Comment: That was what I was going at, thanks for clarifying!