# Microsoft JScript runtime error : Code : 800A1391 'console' is undefined while running node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js. I have created a file named myFirst.js after installing node.js in Windows machine. The file looks like following :

```
console.log("Sweet .. Welcome to Node.js");
```

But when I try to navigate to that directory and execute the file it throws an error like the following :
[image]

Even a command like

[image]

is not working. What am I missing ? How would I execute my first node.js code block ?

Comment: Looks like you're running the code with Windows Script Host and not Node.

Comment: Go to terminal and run `node yourscript.js`

Answer (score 10):

[HALAR's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35834995/4537):

- explains that **`*.js` file are by default executed by Microsoft's obsolescent *WSH* ([Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)) JavaScript engine (*JScript*) rather than Node.js**,
- and that **passing a Node.js `*.js` script directly to the `node.exe` executable ensures its proper execution**.

Alternatively, you can ***reconfigure* file-extension associations so as to make `*.js` files execute with the Node.js engine by default**:

- Open a PowerShell console window.
- Execute the following, which changes the association of the `.js` extension in the Windows registry (which takes effect for the *current* user account only, but, conversely, doesn't require elevation):

```powershell
New-Item -Force HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\NodeJSFile\shell\Open\Command -Value "`"$((Get-Command node.exe).Source)`" `"%1`" %*"
New-Item -Force HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Classes\.js -Value 'NodeJSFile'
```

**From that point on, invoking `*.js` files directly will execute them with Node.js (`node.exe`).**

Note, however, that you'll have to do this on every machine that you want to behave this way.

Answer (score 9):

You must prefix your execution of the *.Js file with the node executable to add context, as if to say, "open this file with the node scripting engine, rather than the default Microsoft scripting engine, which does not recognize the 'console' object."

Therefore, instead of simply providing the name of the .Js file, like so:

```
myFirst.js
```

Change it to:

```
node myFirst.js
```

The name of the *.js file acts as a parameter to the node executable, which is then executed, providing you with your "Sweet.. Welcome to Node.js" statement.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this, first we need to understand that the error is caused because it is being executed by **Windows Script Host**.

Now, run the code from your ***cmd promt*** with the following syntax:

```
>node myFirst.js
```

or

```
>node <application_name>.js
```

this will allow the Node.js application to open through **V8 JavaScript engine**(Google's).

*P.S: Please reply back if this has helped in resolving your issue else post the problem you are facing after **trying** this.*

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error when was trying to run [NodeJs Script](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_get_started.asp) ,I saved the script with name similar to "node" command like

> node.js

and when I tried to run

```
node node.js
```

throw the error Jscript runtime error

so I just replace the name with some other like,also delete the script with name node.js

> nodescript.js

then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this post [What exactly does "/usr/bin/env node" do at the beginning of node files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509816/what-exactly-does-usr-bin-env-node-do-at-the-beginning-of-node-files)

You will need to add `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the beginning of your script.  This works even on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in windows 8 with my example `hello_word.js`:

1. So I install the node js `7.7.2 vesion` in disk `D`, because there is question of rights and System sécurity when you install in disk `c`, so it is more difficult to work in disk `c`
2. when I finished the install wizard, I lunch "cmd" and then I change my position to the `d:/ nodejs` by using `cd d:/nodejs`
3. then there is two issues:

   1. execute the `node hello_word.js`
   2. or at first execute `node`, so now you are in the node session, then execute `requiere('./hello_word.js')`

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please remove if any `node.js` file in the program file path.

In the below directory or folder(file path) `node.js` file exists.

```
C:/Education/Node/node.js
```

Remove `node.js`

Then run in command prompt in file myFirst.js file path

```
node myFirst.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use node js as file name, just remane node.js file name to other and try

Answer (score 0):

if you still get "'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." error after node yourjsfile.js command on Windows

type node and enter first then type .load .\yourjsfile.js and enter again