# node_modules/.bin/package.cmd file in node js

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am new to node js. I am trying to build a npm module and confused a bit with cmd file present in /node_modules/.bin folder with the name of the package locally.

I installed multiple packages as dependencies and found that cmd files are different.

jade.cmd

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\jade\bin\jade" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\jade\bin\jade" %*
)
```

mocha-casperjs.cmd

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\/bin/sh.exe" (
  "%~dp0\/bin/sh.exe"  "%~dp0\..\mocha-casperjs\bin\mocha-casperjs" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  /bin/sh  "%~dp0\..\mocha-casperjs\bin\mocha-casperjs" %*
)
```

My question is, if it is auto-generated by NPM, why npm creates 2 different files for 2 different packages. Is is something a user creates and tells NPM?

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr**

**On Windows, `npm` creates the wrapper batch file (`*.cmd`) based on whatever shell/interpreter is specified in the script file's *shebang line*.**

---

What you're seeing is **npm's emulation of the *Unix* [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) mechanism for *Windows***, where the very 1st line of an executable plain-text file (script), if it starts with magic characters `#!`, tells the OS what interpreter/shell to pass the script to for execution (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375) of mine for more information).

Since Windows doesn't support shebang lines, `npm` creates a *wrapper* `*.cmd` (batch) file, that explicitly invokes the "binary" file (the script file specified in the `bin` key of `package.json`) with whatever executable is specified in the script file's shebang line.

In other words: **`npm` parses the script's shebang line to determine what shell/interpreter to invoke, and creates the wrapper batch script accordingly.**

If we peek at `./bin/jade.js` inside the `jade` package, we see `#!/usr/bin/env node` as the shebang line, which is why the `jade.cmd` wrapper file invokes `node.exe`.
This is the **typical case**: a **script written in JavaScript** that must be **executed by the Node.js engine**.

However, **any other shell/interpreter may be specified too**, but doing so **only makes sense if a given shell/interpreter is also available on *Windows***; for `node`, that is a given, but, as the contents of `mocha-casper.cmd` shows, it makes no sense with the *Unix default shell*, `/bin/sh` (the `./bin/mocha-casperjs` file from package `mocha-casper.js` contains shebang line `#!/bin/sh`).

The makers of the `mocha-casperjs` have chosen to roll their own Windows integration by *re-implementing* the Unix shell script for `cmd.exe` as  `mocha-casperjs.bat` (also a batch file) - however, since `npm` is unaware of this, this batch file is not placed in the PATH (global) / not discoverable by name only (when calling CLIs in a project context).

More generally, **for scripts to also work on Windows, it doesn't make sense to use shebang lines with *absolute, POSIX-style paths*** - **EXCEPT** if the target shell/interpreter is specified by ***indirect* invocation via `/usr/bin/env`**, which signals to `npm` that it should be looked for in the PATH (again, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375) of mine for more information).
(Additionally, the wrapper batch files also look in their *own* directory for the executable, but that is rarely helpful, given that `npm` wouldn't copy them there even if you explicitly added them as an entry in your `package.json`'s `bin` key.)

As an aside: recent versions of `npm` *also* create extension-less wrapper scripts for Unix environments, notably Cygwin, and Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.

---

**When creating your own packages**, for CLIs ("binaries") - directly executable scripts that act like command-line utilities - that are part of an npm package to **work on Windows too**, you must:

- **Add a shebang line to your scripts** - even if you only ever intend to run them on Windows.
- **Define that shebang line as `#!/usr/bin/env <interpreter-executable-filename-without-extension>`**; typically - if your script is written in JavaScript and must be executed with `node` - use:
  `#!/usr/bin/env node`
- In your **`package.json`** file's `bin` key, **define the script's key *without extension*.**, because `.cmd` is directly appended to the key name when the wrapper batch file is created (on Unix, a symlink is created named for the key as-is); e.g.:
  `"bin": { "foo": "./bin/fooj.js" }`
- **Caveat**: If the script pointed to by the `bin` key in `package.json` has extension `.js` but *has no shebang line*, the wrapper script will invoke the `.js` file *directly*, which will by default execute it with [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) (specifically, with *JScript*, its JavaScript engine) rather than Node.js, which won't work as intended - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33975327/45375) for what symptoms you would see.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell npm to make executable file provided with your package accessible from `./node_modules/.bin` directory (in case of local install) or globally (when module is installed globally). You should place `bin` field into `package.json` and specify relative path to script. For example, jade `package.json` contains the following code:

```
"bin": {
  "jade": "./bin/jade.js"
}
```

When installing jade package, npm makes this script (`./bin/jade.js`) accessible by generating, if neccessary, wrapper script (`jade.cmd`) which contents depend on current OS, shell, and the type of script you wish to make accessble. Jade uses `.js` script, and npm generates `jade.cmd` for your OS that will launch node and pass script name as argument. But mocha-casperjs uses shell scripts, so contents of generated `mocha-casperjs.cmd` are different — it starts `sh.exe` instead of node.

You can read about `bin` field of `package.json` here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin

Comment: bin in package.json tells npm where package executable is. But when you install a package, npm install it in the node_modules/jade (jade is just an example) and add a cmd file in node_modules/.bin/jade.cmd which points to the node_modules/jade/bin/jade.

Comment: @prabhat, yes, you are right. I wrote about generation of cmd file npm places into node_modules/.bin directory. You cannot manually change contents of this cmd file, it is autogenerated. Is it answers your question, or i did not understand you?

Comment: If npm generates it, why it is different for 2 packages, is my question. I cannot find anything on google about it so I asked here.

Comment: @prabhat, i wrote about it. It is because jade package.json specifies javascript file (which runs through node.exe) in bin option, and mocha-casperjs specifies shell script which runs through sh.exe command interpreter. Because of it, npm generates one script for jade (which starts node) and different one for mocha-casperjs (which starts sh.exe). If mocha-casperjs author specifed js file in bin option, npm would generate exactly the same cmd file as the one generated for jade (except for the file names, of course).