# issue with node.js not executing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

Okay so I am really new to server-side scripting but love to give it a try. My issue thus far is that when I attempt to launch a file like "hellonode.js" I cannot. 
[I launch node and attempt to access a file from within a folder called new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WjlU.png)

and I get this error:

[console is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFvw1.png)

however when I use node and manually type the address in I get the intended results 
[the javascript application works completely as intended](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBLHR.png)

I really wanna know why it is I cannot execute Node from within a folder but if I manually go to it each time I can. It is rather frustrating

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft JScript runtime error : Code : 800A1391 'console' is undefined while running node.js program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975327/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-code-800a1391-console-is-undefined-while-r)

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 1):

When you are going to execute a node script the 1st argument to node should be the uri of the script file. so

`node path/to/your/nodeScript`

path would be absolute or relative to your current working directory.

also you can run a node script by giving only the folder of the node script but you need to create the node script file as `index.js`

suppose you have a folder name `MyFirstNodeScript` and inside the folder there is a file named `index.js` the script would be

```
console.log('hello world!!!');
```

now you can run the script by `node MyFirstNodeScript` but you should be in the parent directory of the `MyFirstNodeScript`

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you get the error but essentially you just "opened" a `.js` file in windows, which resulted in windows JScript executing your file instead of node executing your file. Maybe because your `node.js` file, or do you simple double-click?

Basically if you want a file to double-click to start your server create a short `.bat` file that contains the working snippet to start your node script. However in reality you usually don't need a thing to double click at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give the address to the current file in the directory. It's more of a command line way of executing files rather than a node js convention.

```
node .\hellonode.js
```

In Unix (Linux or Mac) command lines it should be like this:

```
node ./hellonode
```