# How do I run a JS file with node without getting sent Error: 800A1391?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, npm

I would like to run the code:

```js
console.log("Node is installed!");
```

This is clearly error-less code, but upon running it, I get this error:
[Stupid Error 800A1391](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0aaL.png)

I looked up how to fix this, and they told me to run the file like this:

```node
node myfirst.js
```

I looked more around the internet and was directed to update everything, and check the versions. I have node, NPM, Java, and javascript installed. I still can't run this with updated systems. Even with a blank file, it still sends error codes. I tried running it, all these ways:

```node
node myfirst.js
npm myfirst.js
run myfirst.js
myfirst.js
```

All of these attempts were illfated, resulting in code 800A1391. Any help alternate to the answers I have seen several times online would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time in reading this.

Comment: try checking your node version in the terminal like. `node -v`

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975327/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-code-800a1391-console-is-undefined-while-r)

Comment: Make sure you have the correct environment variables set for your operating system.

Comment: simply run 'node' in your command prompt/terminal and see if it takes you to node REPL mode. If it does not then set your env. variables correctly.