# How can I suppress “Terminate batch job (Y/N)” confirmation in PowerShell?

Tags: node.js, powershell, job-control

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in PowerShell, I receive:

> Terminate batch job (Y/N)?

Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation, except for Windows PowerShell.

**Does PowerShell provide any more control over batch jobs than what CMD does?**

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that message unless you're running batch scripts from PowerShell. Those are launched as CMD child processes, hence they behave like any other CMD/batch process.

Comment: FWIW, PowerShell can break into a running script if you press Ctrl-Pause(Break).

Comment: See also [How to Disable Ctrl-C /Ctrl-S While Running a Batch File](http://serverfault.com/a/109715)

Comment: If you run the node application with `npm start` the process is automatically wrapped into a CMD/batch process. Try to run the app directly with `node app.js` or whatever.

Comment: For a solution that works in Powershell using Autohotkey, see: https://superuser.com/a/1703017/351521

Comment: just an alternate for someone like me facing this issue with the vs-code terminal, do set the bash as the default terminal(bash doesn't show up that message), and that is it. Thanks, can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- The **cause** of the problem is that **`gulp`** (and any other command that shows this message) is actually a ***batch file* (`*.cmd`, `*.bat`)** and the **behavior is *built into `cmd.exe`***, the interpreter of batch files.
- Package managers are increasingly providing *PowerShell* scripts (`*.ps1`) as well (see bottom section), which bypasses the problem when running from PowerShell.

---

The **behavior is neither caused by PowerShell nor can PowerShell change it** (as evidenced by the [PowerShell source-code repo](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/search?q=Terminate+batch+job&unscoped_q=Terminate+batch+job&type=Code) not containing the prompt message).

The **behavior is *built into `cmd.exe`*** - Powershell, in this case, is calling a `.cmd` file (batch file), which is interpreted by `cmd.exe`.

- **If you explicitly control the invocation of the target executable, you can fix this by moving to Powershell** - note this has its own considerations, see below.
- **If you do not explicitly control the invocation of the target executable, you're out of luck** (unless you're willing to install third-party `cmd.exe` replacements) and must **press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> *twice*** in order to terminate execution.
- **A[n ill-advised] *workaround* is to *modify the `cmd.exe` binary*** - see [article with instructions on how to patch the `cmd.exe` executable in order to suppress the prompt](https://itsme.home.xs4all.nl/projects/misc/patching-cmdexe.html). Additionally, you can post a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/console) to request that this behavior be fixed at the source, though that is unlikely to happen for reasons of backward compatbility.

### To demonstrate the behavior:

The examples assume that Node.js is installed and that `node.exe` is therefore in your PATH:

First, invoke `node.exe` directly, with a tight loop that requires you to press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to terminate the process.

```bash
PS> node -e "while (true);"
```

As you'll see, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> *instantly* terminates the process - no confirmation prompt.

Now, let's create a sample batch file that invokes the same command and invoke that batch file:

```bash
PS> "@echo off`nnode -e `"while (true);`"" | Set-Content test.cmd
PS> ./test.cmd
```

As you'll see, pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> now presents the undesired `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` prompt. (You'd get the same behavior if you ran the batch file from `cmd.exe`.)

### To demonstrate that `gulp` is a `.cmd` (batch) file:

You say you're running your command via [`gulp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp)'s CLI.

**On Windows, the entry point for the `gulp` CLI is `gulp.cmd` [*see update in the bottom section*] - i.e., a *batch file*.** That is how it works in general for `npm`-package "binaries" (executables) implemented as either JS files or shell scripts.

That `gulp` invokes `gulp.cmd` can be verified as follows:

```bash
# Execute from a project folder that has `gulp` installed as a dependency.
# If `gulp` is installed *globally* 
# Note: CLI `npx` requires npm version 5.2.0+
PS C:\some\NodeJs\project> npx where gulp
```

You'll see something like:

```bash
C:\some\NodeJs\project\node_modules\.bin\gulp
C:\some\NodeJs\project\node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd
```

Note that `where.exe` also lists the *extension-less* *Unix*-shell script, `...\gulp`; however, from `cmd.exe` / Powershell such a shell script isn't directly executable, and it is `...\gulp.cmd` - the *batch file* - that is executed.
(If in doubt, place a command such as `@set /p dummy="Press a key"` at the start of the `gulp.cmd` file, and you'll see that this command executes when you invoke `gulp` without the `.cmd` extension.
Also note that there is *no* `gulp.exe`.)

More generally, on Windows, a project's `node_modules\.bin` subfolder contains *pairs* of CLI entry points for the CLIs that come with packages that the project depends on locally:

- `node_modules\.bin\<some-cli>` is the Unix shell script (whose executing interpreter is controlled via its [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375)).
- `node_modules\.bin\<some-cli>.cmd` is the helper batch file for *Windows*.

---

#### Updates and future considerations:

In the context of npm modules, the problem would go away if a *PowerShell* script (`*.ps1`) were used as the helper script on Windows. There are tickets for `npm`, `yarn` and similar software to do this. There are also some drawbacks:

- `*.ps1` files aren't directly executable from outside of PowerShell, notably from `cmd.exe` and File Explorer (and changing that is nontrivial).
- PowerShell still hasn't fully replaced `cmd.exe` as the default shell, as of Windows 10 (and won't anytime soon, if ever).

When called ***from PowerShell*, a `*.ps1` file would be found and run in-process**, so **a possible solution is for the `npm` project to *also* provide `*.ps1` helper scripts**, which would take precedence over `*.cmd` files of the same name.

- **Update**:

  - **Recent versions of `npm` (verified in 6.14.10) indeed DO install such `*.ps1` files.**
  - Alternative package manager **[`yarn`](https://yarnpkg.com/), *since v2* does not seem to use batch files anymore at all, so the original problem is *bypassed* there**; (*v1*, by contrast, still uses batch files (only); upgrading from v1 must be done on a *per-project* basis see the [migration instructions](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/migration)).

Comment: Nice writeup as always.  Do you know whether cmd listens to any other signals besides SIGINT to terminate?

Comment: Thanks, @MaximilianBurszley - unfortunately, I do not know.

Comment: I added a quick summary and saw you undid it but your tl;dr works well too 

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to fix it in VSCode. They've added the ability to handle this kind of occurance.

Edit

> .vscode/settings.json

Append to the bottom of file

```
"terminal.integrated.autoReplies": {
  "Terminate batch job (Y/N)": "Y\r"
}
```

Now one press of "CTRL + C" will end the application

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer notes, the correct **fix** is to  replace `cmd` scripts with `ps1` versions.

However another **workaround** for users of the Hyper shell is ['Hyper yes', a plugin that automatically hits `y` for you](https://hyper.is/store/hyper-yes) when the prompt comes up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

best way to avoid it is to not start it, in my case, is not to type `npm run devStart` but instead type `nodemon ./server.js localhost 3000`
[here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwXgF.png)

Comment: This does not explain why one command is a batch job and another isn't. The explanation is that one of the commands executes multiple commands in one line (like chaining with && for example), and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctr-c again** after the "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"

As far back as thirteen years ago this was the **third** best answer (why third ?) at https://superuser.com/questions/35698/how-to-supress-terminate-batch-job-y-n-confirmation

(I just found it again while trying to eliminate this annoying message)

Comment: That’s not an answer to the question being asked, which is how to suppress the text so it doesn’t appear.

Comment: @mikemaccana Read the question again  ... "confirmation"

Comment: Yes. This answer doesn’t attempt to suppress the confirmation.

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off
start /w "" "C:\myfile.bat" 2>nul|findstr /i "termin"

if errorlevel 1 goto bypass


:bypass

echo hello

timeout /t 5 >nul
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of your code?