# When I tested using Jest, I was unable to exit the process correctly in both Powershell and Git-base terminals

Tags: node.js, powershell, debugging, jestjs, git-bash

I am debugging the node.js process, and using process.exit allows it to exit normally, but it does not work if using ctrl+c. Why is this? Then my colleagues can also log out normally, but I get stuck and have to create a new terminal every time.

Do I find that terminating batch operations when popping up (y/n)? At this point, if I press y and then enter, I can do it, but I can't just use Ctrl+C directly

[image]
[image]

I want to know what the reason is and how I can avoid this situation

Comment: As for the `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` prompt: Unfortunately, you cannot avoid this prompt when you're calling a _batch file_ (`.cmd` or `.bat`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892407/45375) for background information. Generally, if the program you're running intercepts and ignores Ctrl-C, there's nothing the calling shell can do.