# Bash: how to wait for a command to finish running to parse out a string?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script that needs to let `npm run server` finish running which will output an ID number that I need

`npm run server` outputs

```
running server...
....
...
...
Server version is /id/1345
```

I need to parse out the `1345` after the command finishes running.

I've attempted the following but without success:

```
idd=$(npm run server "$domain" &> >(sed -E -e 's:(^.*)(id/)(.*$):\3:g'))
echo $idd
```

which throws:

```
run.sh: command substitution: line 27: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

I've also tried:

```
bundle_counter=$(npm run server "$domain" | sed -E -e 's:(^.*)(/b/)(.*$):\3:g')
```

which fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The *immediate problem*:

The error message indicates that **you're invoking Bash as `sh`** (or at least in POSIX-compatibility mode), in which case **process substitutions (`<(...)` and `>(...)`) aren't supported**, because they're **not part of POSIX**.

*If* your  `sed` command worked in principle, it would suffice to ensure that your command is run by `bash` - invoked *by that name*, using [shebang line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375) `#!/bin/bash`.

That said, using an output process substitution is needlessly complicated.

#### The problem with your `sed` command:

Your `sed` command doesn't work as intended, because, in the absence of option `-n`, `sed` still prints *all* (potentially modified) input lines, not just the (modified) line of interest.
Thus, any line that your `s` (substitution) command's regular expression *doesn't* match, is *still printed, as-is*.

See [Ewan Mellor's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44144976/45375) for a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
idd=$(npm run server "$domain" | sed -n -E '$s+id/(.*)$+\1+p')
```

I piped npm's output to sed, like you did in your second snippet. The `-E` flag, which you also used, enables extended regexes. Those aren't even needed here now that I think of it, but it's kind of standard because EREs are more useful.

`-n` tells sed to by default not print its buffer when going to the next line. It does more or less the same as when you'd use `d` on every input line after all other commands. When using `-n` you have to explicitly ask sed to print certain lines, with the `p` command – but that's actually not used here, as we'll shortly see!

The `$` will make sure that the command is only executed on the last line of the input.

The `s` command is the replacement command. You can use any character right after it and that will be `s`'s delimiter. The classic is `/` but here I've used `+` since we are using a `/` in the needle and this way we don't have to escape the `/`. `id/(.*)$` is the needle and `\1` is the replacement. You don't have to anchor your strings like you do, so a needle of `^(.*)id/(.*)$` and corresponding replacement `\2` is equivalent but redundant (and will most likely impose a slight performance overhead).

Because there's no semicolon after `s`, `p` is actually not a separate command here, but a flag to `s`. It will print the buffer iff the `s` command was successful in finding something to replace.

Answer (score 2):

```
idd=$(npm run server "$domain" 2>&1 | sed -E -ne 's:(^.*)(id/)(.*$):\3:p')
```

- `2>&1` to merge stderr onto stdout.
- A simple pipe to pass the output to sed.
- `-n` on the sed command to not print any non-matching lines.
- `p` at the end of the regex to print the match.

Comment: Nicely done; definitely the most straightforward translation of the OP's failed attempt. May be worth mentioning that the 1st and 2nd capture groups aren't needed, so `sed -E -ne 's:^.*/id/(.*$):\1:p')` would do.