# node.js command line application not runs

Tags: node.js

I am building a node js command line pacakge, and when I am linking one of my projects to the command line project when I am trying to use the command, it's trying to open it like a js file on windows, and not as a node js application.

this is the command line project package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sitemap-generator",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "^2.19.0",
    "esm": "^3.0.84",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security"
  },
  "bin": {
    "smg": "./cli.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=9.5"
  }
}
```

and the index.js file:

```
'use strict';

const program = require('commander');

program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .description('Contact management system');

program.parse(process.argv);
```

the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command you want to run is `node index.js [arguments]` instead of opening the js file directly.

Comment: but i am trying to run this command throw another project of me, that i linked via `git link`.

Comment: take the assumption that I am an experienced javascript developer

Comment: In that case I'd recommend that you export the function you're trying to call from your index.js in your `module.exports` and run the function directly from the app that's calling this.

Comment: so my index.js is now `module.exports = require("./bin/cli");`, and this isnt helping.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to add the following line to the top of the cli.js file: `#!/usr/bin/env node`

so the file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const program = require('commander');

program
    .version('0.0.1')
    .description('Contact management system');

program.parse(process.argv);
```

[@mklement0 - #!/usr/bin/env node is an instance of a shebang line...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/9993548)