# Why does PowerShell not recognize quoted parameters?

Tags: windows, powershell, parameters, quotes

Why does PowerShell treat quoted parameters differently when you invoke the script directly (in a PowerShell console or ISE) or when you invoke it via another PowerShell instance?

Here is the script (`TestQuotes.ps1`):

```
param
(
    [string]
    $Config = $null
)

"Config = $Config"
```

Here are the results:

```
PS D:\Scripts> .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C"
Config = A B C
PS D:\Scripts> PowerShell .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C"
Config = A
PS D:\Scripts> .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config 'A B C'
Config = A B C
PS D:\Scripts> PowerShell .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config 'A B C'
Config = A
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the ones that call powershell.exe are NOT doing the same thing as the ones that start a script with parameters. take a look at `powershell.exe /?` for some ideas. it's mostly the way you are handing strings to the exe file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [PowerShell.exe Command-Line Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help), the first argument for the `powershell` executable is `-Command`:

```
PowerShell[.exe]
       [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>]
                     | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
       [-EncodedCommand <Base64EncodedCommand>]
       [-ExecutionPolicy <ExecutionPolicy>]
       [-File <FilePath> [<Args>]]
       [-InputFormat {Text | XML}]
       [-Mta]
       [-NoExit]
       [-NoLogo]
       [-NonInteractive]
       [-NoProfile]
       [-OutputFormat {Text | XML}]
       [-PSConsoleFile <FilePath> | -Version <PowerShell version>]
       [-Sta]
       [-WindowStyle <style>]

PowerShell[.exe] -Help | -? | /?
```

> Any text after `-Command` is sent as a single command line to PowerShell.
>
> ...
>
> When the value of `-Command` is a string, `Command` must be the last parameter specified because **any characters typed after the command are interpreted as the command arguments**.

What child PowerShell instance actually receives is easy to check with [echoargs](https://chocolatey.org/packages/echoargs):

```
PS > echoargs .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C"
Arg 0 is <.\TestQuotes.ps1>
Arg 1 is <-Config>
Arg 2 is <A B C>
```

Which is further parsed by the child instance to:

```
'.\TestQuotes.ps1' '-Config' 'A' 'B' 'C'
```

And this is where you get your "wrong" result: `Config = A`

If you specify `-File` argument, you'll get the desired result:

```
PS >  PowerShell -File .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config 'A B C'
Config = A B C

PS >  PowerShell -Command .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config 'A B C'
Config = A
```

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr**

If you're **calling another PowerShell instance *from PowerShell*, use a *script block* (`{ ... }`)** to get predictable behavior:

Windows PowerShell:

```bash
# To pass arguments to the script block, append -args ...
powershell.exe { .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C" }
```

PowerShell *Core*:

```bash
# To pass arguments to the script block, append -args ...
pwsh { .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C" }
```

This **will make the quoting of arguments work as expected** - and it will even return *objects* with near-type fidelity from the invocation, because serialization similar to that used for PowerShell remoting is employed.

Note, however, that this is ***not* an option when calling from *outside* of PowerShell**, such as from `cmd.exe` or `bash`.

Read on for an explanation of the behavior you saw in the *absence* of a script block.

---

The **PowerShell CLI** (calling `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) / `pwsh.exe` (PowerShell *Core*) **supports only *one* parameter that accepts a *positional* argument** (i.e., a value not preceded by a *parameter name* such as `-Command`).

- In **Windows PowerShell,** that (implied) parameter is **`-Command`**.
- In **PowerShell *Core***, it is **`-File`**.

  - The default had to be changed to support use of the CLI in Unix [shebang lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375).

Any arguments *after* the first positional argument, if any, are considered:

- in Windows PowerShell: *part of the snippet of PowerShell source code* passed to the (implied) 
  `-Command` parameter.
- in PowerShell *Core*: *individual arguments* to *pass as literals* to the *script file* specified in the *first positional argument* (the implied `-File` argument).

---

**Arguments passed to `-Command` - whether implicitly or explicitly - undergo *two* rounds of parsing** by PowerShell, which can be tricky:

- In the *first* round, the `"..."` (double quotes) enclosing individual arguments are *stripped*.

  - If you're calling *from PowerShell*, this even applies to arguments that were *originally* `'...'`-enclosed (single-quoted), because, behind the scenes, PowerShell *re-quotes* such arguments to use `"..."` when calling *external programs* (which includes the PowerShell CLI itself).
- In the *second* round, the stripped arguments are *joined with spaces* to form a *single string* that is *then* interpreted as *PowerShell source code*.

---

Applied to your invocation, this means that *both* `PowerShell .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C"` and `PowerShell .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config 'A B C'` resulted in PowerShell ultimately parsing and executing the following code:

```bash
.\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config A B C
```

That is, **due to the 2 rounds of parsing, the original quoting was *lost*, resulting in *three* distinct arguments getting passed**, which explains your symptom.

---

If you had to **make your command work *without* a script block**, you have two options:

- **Use `-File`**, which **only applies *one* round of parsing**:

  ```bash
    powershell.exe -File .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "A B C"
  ```

  - That is, **aside from stripping the enclosing `"..."`, the resulting arguments are treated as *literals*** - which, however, is *typically* what you want.
- **With (implied) `-Command`, apply an *extra layer of quoting***:

  ```bash
    powershell.exe -Command .\TestQuotes.ps1 -Config "'A B C'"
  ```

The outer `"..."` are stripped during command-line parsing, leaving the inner, single-quoted `'A B C'` string as part of the code to be executed.
If you wanted to use `"` for the inner quoting as well (not necessary here), you'd have to use `"\"A B C\""` from *outside* PowerShell and `` "\`"A B C\`"" ``<sup>[1]</sup> from *inside* PowerShell - that is, PowerShell requires `"` chars. to be escaped as `\"` in arguments passed *to its CLI*, whereas *inside PowerShell*, `` `" `` (or `""`) must be used.

---

<sup>[1] The `\` escaping *in addition* to `` ` `` shouldn't be necessary, but unfortunately is due to a long-standing bug up to at least PowerShell 7.2.x, which *may* get fixed in 7.3 - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)</sup>