# What's the correct way to open powershell core in a new window?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

This command opens a new powershell window, runs the commands, and then exits:

```
Start-Process powershell { echo "hello"; sleep 1; echo "two"; sleep 1; echo "goodbye" }
```

If I instead launch Powershell Core, it opens a new window but the new window exits immediately:

```
Start-Process pwsh { echo "hello"; sleep 1; echo "two"; sleep 1; echo "goodbye" }
```

What's the correct way to do this sort of invocation with pwsh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a script block (`{ ... }`) with [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) - it binds *as a string* to the `-ArgumentList` parameter, which means its *literal contents* - except for the enclosing `{` and `}` - is passed.

- In *Windows PowerShell* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)), the CLI's default parameter is `-Command`.
- In PowerShell *Core* (v6+, [`pwsh.exe` / `pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)), it is `-File`<sup>[1]</sup>, which is why your command fails.

In PowerShell Core, you must therefore use `-Command` (`-c`) explicitly:

```
Start-Process pwsh '-c', 'echo "hello"; sleep 1; echo "two"; sleep 1; echo "goodbye"'
```

---

<sup>[1] This change was necessary in order to properly support use of PowerShell Core in [shebang lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/45375) on Unix-like platforms.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you ran `start-process -nonewwindow`, you would see the error message "cannot find the file".  And running a script like this should work:  `start-process pwsh .\script.ps1`.